# How to mark the fields of a view shown in a table as already read?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I have a view that displays the results as a table, and also contains an exposed taxonomy filter. I need a way to know when a certain field in a row has a value that has already been "seen". A row with a "seen" value is less useful compared to "unseen" rows. Therefore, the table needs to visually distinguish between seen and unseen rows, perhaps by highlighting seen rows, or fading them.

How could I determine when the field has a value that has been "seen", and then style rows with a "seen" value differently?

Comment: Sounds like a job for the Flags module. And then maybe `hook_entity_view` to add the Flag that links user and node ID.

Comment: Maybe worth looking at https://www.drupal.org/project/recently_read as well.